# How to Pretty Print a Json which is escaped using gson library?

Tags: json, gson, escaping, pretty-print

I have a simple Json that I've escaped using the following code:

```
Gson gs = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
String abc = gs.toJson(payload);
```

However, this prints the Json in the following way:

```
"{\r\n  \"dob\": \"T2XA\",\r\n  \"name\": \"Test Group 30thOct3\",\r\n  \"address\": \"Household\"\r\n}"
```

I need this to be in pretty format:

```
"{\r\n" + 
    "  \"dob\": \"T2XA\",\r\n" + 
    "  \"name\": \"Test Group 30thOct3\",\r\n" + 
    "  \"address\": \"Household\"\r\n" + 
"}"
```

Is there any way to do this using Google gson library? I'm pretty new to handling Jsons and not sure how to achieve this

Comment: It's kind of an insane idea. Why do you need this and why do you think Gson should do it? Gson does pretty-printing quite well, and what you actually need (for whatever reason) is string escaping that can be accomplished by pretty-printing JSON to a string (or a stream, whatever), then escaping by a Java literal encoder, then splitting by `"\r\n"`, and then joining accordingly to generate a legal concatenation expression. Are you going to copy/paste the JSON output to your code, right?

Comment: Apparently this might sound like an insane idea, but this is the exact requirement that I have for my current project. All the input payloads are initialized into String variables in the above format and now, we are trying to generate that automatically using a piece of code. However, your answer helps, I get a fair idea as to how to approach this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

These two strings are the same actually. It's called pretty because there's indent when you print it into console or text file like below.

```
{
  "dob": "T2XA",
  "name": "Test Group 30thOct3",
  "address": "Household"
}
```

Comment: The question is not whether the two formats are same or different. The question is HOW to print the json in pretty format with escape characters present?